# Problems with labeling of Chapter 0

Tags: labels

I'm writing a final year project and I would like to start it with a "Preliminaries" chapter, whose number I'd like to be 0. I do the trivial `\setcounter{chapter}{-1}`, which makes the number of the chapter 0, but it also makes all formulae and all figures in the chapter be labeled as (1), (2), ..., instead of (0.1), (0.2), ... How can I fix this?

PS I am not sure which package governs the formulae/figures labeling. I use `amsmath`, if this matters.

```
\documentclass[oneside, a4paper, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{-1}
\chapter{Preliminaries}

Text here...

\begin{equation}\label{eq}
    f = f(x)...
\end{equation}

I would like the label to be (0.1) instead of \eqref{eq}.

\chapter{Next chapter}

Compare the labels:

\begin{equation}
    g = g (x)...
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add the following line in your preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside, a4paper, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{-1}
\chapter{Preliminaries}

Text here...

\begin{equation}\label{eq}
    f = f(x)...
\end{equation}

I would like the label to be (0.1) instead of \eqref{eq}.

\chapter{Next chapter}

Compare the labels:

\begin{equation}
    g = g (x)...
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The original definition in `report.cls` is

```
\renewcommand\theequation
  {\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \thechapter.\fi \@arabic\c@equation}
```

which means that the chapter number is printed only when greater than zero.

Comment: I'd prefer the easier `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}`

Comment: @egreg You're right. No need for low-level commands.

Comment: @Newbie You're welcome. Remember that you can accept (and upvote) the answer, if you want. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)